# Помогите с ошибкой list indices must be integers or slices, not datetime.timedelta

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть такой код:

```
d=0
c=0
m=0
while True:  
    a = datetime.now()
    b = datetime(2020, 1, 1)
    c = b - a
    ab=[]
    print(c)
    ab.append(c.days)
    ab.append(c.seconds//3600)
    ab.append(c.seconds//60)
    print("Days: " + str(ab[d]) +"Hours: "+ str(ab[c])+"Minutes: "+str(ab[m]))
    d=d+1
    m=m+1
    c=c+1
```

Должно по логике все работать,но выдаёт такую ошибку:

`list indices must be integers or slices, not datetime.timedelta`

Помогите разобраться,что не так.

Comment: Как раз по логике и не должно работать. Что такое ab[d]?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Дело в том, что у переменной c тип получается datetime.timedelta:

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> a = datetime.now()
>>> b = datetime(2020, 1, 1)
>>> a - b
datetime.timedelta(-3, 70594, 135008)
```

И ошибка в части ab[c]. В целом, лучше вместо списка использовать переменные, но можно и так:

```
print("Days: " + str(ab[1) + "Hours: " + str(ab[2]) + "Minutes: " + str(ab[3]))
```

Comment: а какие именно переменные?

Comment: Ну, например: days = c.days. Такого плана.